# Upload multiple files PHP

Tags: php, arrays, upload, handle

Hi I'm trying to upload multiple files(with array) and it doesn't works..

When I upload just 1 files it works fine, but when I choose more than 1 file it doesn't upload them corectly beacause it creates the files with names and extensions corectly but there size is 0 bytes.

Here is My Code:

```
$count = 0;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $i => $name) {
        if (strlen($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/'.$name)) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the errors array to see if any of the files encounter an error on upload

Comment: print_r($_FILES) to see if you're accessing them right. Idk, I've never had occasion to upload more than 1 file at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $count = 0;
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  for ($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['file']);$i++) {
    if (strlen($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/'.$name)) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
   }
 }
```